# Alamofire could not update class property data

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i am trying to use alamofire to download json weather data. **Here is my code, the working version:**

```
class WeatherModel {
  private var _date: String?
  private var _location: String?
  private var _weatherType: String?
  private var _temperature: Double?

  func getWeatherInfoFromAPI(completed: @escaping ()-> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: WEATHER_URL)!
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
    // Test updating data
    self._temperature = 25
    self._weatherType = "Clear"
    self._location = "Vietnam"
    completed()
    })

  }
}
```

-> This way, i am able to update the property of the class.

**Failing to update class property version of getWeatherInfoFromAPI func:**

```
      func getWeatherInfoFromAPI(completed: @escaping ()-> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: WEATHER_URL)!
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON{ response in
        // Test updating data
        self._temperature = 25
        self._weatherType = "Clear"
        self._location = "Vietnam"  
    }
    completed()
  }
```

So, i dont know what is the difference between them. Please help me to clarify between 2 ways here.

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in })
```

and

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON{ response in }
```

What is the reason that my code does not work? Since i see the Alamofire docs also use like the second way! I am thinking about thread difference between them

Also, how do i know what thread the code is running in responseJSON?

Thanks, i appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

Those two ways are functionally identical, the second one just uses Swift's trailing closure syntax.

What do you do in `completed()`? Because in first example, you are calling it upon completion of network call, and in second case you are calling it immediately after you **start** the network call - the call is not completed yet. You should call if in Alamofire callback, like in first example. In second example, if you're inspecting those properties inside `completed`, then it's no wonder they're not updated yet.

Comment: It means that after alamofire request starts in background, it comes back right away to main thread to do the completion in the second way. Therefore it has been received data yet

Comment: Have in mind, that those two examples you pasted differ not only in Alamofire callback syntax you used, but also where you placed your `completed()` call. In first example you placed `completed()` call in alamofire callback, in second you placed it outside. That is the reason, to the closure syntax you used.

Comment: How about if i want to update the UI in completed(). What thread is it running, since updating UI should be done in main thread, isn't it?

Comment: Network calls run in some background thread, so any UI operations should be called on main thread `DispatchQueue.main.async { // do stuff here }`